# scala-match control chars at odd positions

Tags: scala

I have the output of char2hex() from a database column which is a string of hex characters like "41424320202020200A20". I need to check if this hex sequence contains any control character i.e between ascii range \x00 to \x1F (Line feed, Form feed, Carriage return, etc).

I can check like

```
scala> val x = "41424320202020200A20"
x: String = 41424320202020200A20

scala> x.contains("0A")
res107: Boolean = true

scala> x.indexOf("0A")
res109: Int = 16

scala>
```

but I need to ensure that "0A" always matches at the odd position(s) in my string x, so that the hex sequence is correctly checked.

I can combine them like

```
scala> x.indexOf("0A") %2==0  && x.contains("0A")
res111: Boolean = true

scala>
```

But that would stop with only the first occurrence of the control character.

How do I get all the control chars from the hex string?.

Example:- If I have the string like "41424320202020200A200B000C"

then my output should be List("0A","0B","00","0C")

Comment: Does order matter in your output?

Comment: @Benjamin...it doesn't matter.. but if it is possible, then good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for providing a desired output, in this this code it's `res`:

```
val x = "41424320202020200A200B000C"
val controlCharacters = (0x00 to 0x1F).map(c => f"$c%02X".toUpperCase)

val res = (x.toUpperCase.grouped(2).toSeq intersect controlCharacters).toList
```

EDIT: I've put the control character range you've mentioned in a single solution.

Hope it helps.